# JavaScript - Delete All Cookies, not working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this code that won't delete all of my cookies, any idea y?

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN delete server (and js) cookies from javascript unless they are protected with the HttpOnly flag

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete cookies created by javascript. You can't delete cookies create by the server.