# How can I completely disable / eliminate cookies in TiddlyWiki?

Tags: javascript, cookies, tiddlywiki

I really need help on this. I'm developing a TiddlyWiki to act as my organization's navigation tool for finding files on our extremely slow and cumbersome internal website/server.

Problem: Some of the options TiddlyWiki saves to a cookie apparently conflict with the internal website's own cookie options. The TiddlyWiki has to be hosted on / loaded from the internal website and so its cookie has the same url/name as the internal website. Various useful TiddlyWiki plugins leave cookies that either stop one from being able to upload anything to the internal website or even prevent it from opening at all.

Telling every user of this site to delete their cookies after viewing the website is not an option.

I can't get access to the contents of the cookie because our information management permissions process is slow, complicated, and doesn't even understand my problem.

I've done many things to try to solve this:

I used the CookieManager plugin and set it to disallow any cookies, but a cookie was still being dropped.

I tried disabling plugins, re-uploading, and testing. After getting rid of several useful plugins, I was at least able to still access the internal website. However, I would have to disable the advanced search plugin in order to fix the issue with not being able to upload to the internal site. I really need advanced search since it both provides some of the visitor/editor segregation and also is one of the main selling features of using TiddlyWiki for my organization.

I tried renaming the options in the advanced search plugin (in particular) to names that would probably not be used as cookie options by our internal site. This didn't seem to work.

What *does* work is it manually edit the TiddlyWiki source code to comment-out the innards of the saveCookie function:

```
function saveCookie(name)
{
//  var cookies = {};
//  for(var key in config.options) {
//      var value = getOption(key);
//      value = value == null ? 'false' : value;
//      cookies[key] = value;
//  }
//  document.cookie = 'TiddlyWiki=' + String.encodeHashMap(cookies) + '; expires=Fri, 1 Jan 2038 12:00:00 UTC; path=/';
//  cookies = getCookies();
//  for(var c in cookies) {
//      var optType = c.substr(0,3);
//      if(config.optionHandlers[optType])
//          removeCookie(c);
//  }
}
```

My problem, though, is that this has to be done after every upgrade of the TiddlyWiki template, which I sometimes need to do after going through the copy/paste/file-rename steps necessary for Windows to allow TiddlyWiki to save. (These steps often screw up the TiddlyWiki template so that it doesn't think the TiddlyWiki file is valid. It will then refuse to save changes until I upgrade.)

I don't mind doing this manually so much. It's a hassle, but it doesn't take very long. I can't expect any of the other members of our website team to do it, though, and I need to have our TiddlyWiki in a state that it can be maintained/updated without me.

I tried making systemConfig file like this:

```
//{{{
function saveCookie(name) { }
//}}}
```

I thought/hoped it would overwrite the function even when it's intact in the original source code. If it does, it doesn't do it before the TiddlyWiki drops a cookie that screws up [the ability to access] our internal website. I further tried inserting a TiddlyWiki version of the first answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript . This causes TiddlyWiki to freeze. It throws up a stack overflow alert.

I really need help on this since I don't know what else to do, and this is an issue that could possibly jeopard the use of TiddlyWiki by my organization.

Thanks,

Dutch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also asked this question on the TiddlyWiki Google Groups (http://groups.google.com/group/tiddlywiki/browse_thread/thread/b33c696a628e4606) and got several answers.

I was pointed to http://mptw2.tiddlyspot.com/#HijackingHowto, which shows how to redefine core TiddlyWiki functions to, for example, change their behavior under certain conditions.

Most of it was far more than I needed to solve this problem, but just seeing how they redefined their core functions gave me a solution.

The only JavaScript I know I've picked up while tinkering with 
TiddlyWiki, so I don't *fully* understand why what I have now works 
and what I had before didn't, but here's the code that will completely 
kill cookies (and again, it should be inside a plugin tagged systemConfig) :

```
 //{{{ 
 window.saveCookie = function(name) { } 
 //}}}
```

I was thinking it might have something to do with the core TiddlyWiki code running at 
a level where all the declared functions are being assigned to `window`.