# Cookies on localhost in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, localhost

I just want to know if the cookies are created while I  try to access websites on localhost in Google Chrome.

Comment: `http://localhost/`? yes (the protocol doesn't change just because the HTTP server happens to be on the same machine). `file:///path`? no.

Comment: This question and answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694173/manage-cookies-from-google-chrome-extension#

Maybe mark this one as a duplicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if the page on localhost creates a cookie (client-side or server-side).
External resources (images, frames) may also create cookies, depending on your preferences.

You can check it yourself by opening the Developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) -> Resources -> Cookies.

[image: Dev Tools]

Comment: Thanks , so as localhost doesnt create any cookies and changes made in my webpage hosted locally should be reflected once i refresh the page right??

Comment: @Senthil The page may be [**cached**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) (which is usually not affected by cookies). To get the most recent version of the page, use CTRL+F5 to load the page. At the Network tab of the Dev Tools, you can see whether the page is loaded from the cache or not.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to refresh the page. You can also remove the focus from the cookies (i.e. clicking "Session Storage") and then go back to your cookies. The list should be refreshed now.

Comment: any _useful scripting_ for ***delete localhost cookies*** only ?

Answer (score 7):

Simply press F12, open `Application` tab, expand `Cookies` in left menu, right click on `localhost` and  and  and click `Clear`!

[image: Delete cookies of specific site chrome]