# Deleting a cookie created with PHP using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I created a cookie with PHP like so:

```
setcookie('form_login', $_POST['form_login'], time()+3600, "/");
```

I am then trying to delete it using jQuery ([jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)):

```
$.removeCookie('form_login');
```

Doesn't work, cookie still there. Why?

Comment: check if the cookie exists first using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete cookies created by javascript. You can't delete cookies create by the server

[view more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: I should have added that I also tried exactly that with the same result. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: If you set the cookies HttpOnly they can't be read, modified or deleted by Javascript.

Comment: Figured out what's going on: cookie does get deleted, only Firefox, Preferences > Privacy > Remove individual cookies doesn't show the state of cookies in real time (which is extremely deceptive and annoying)