# How can I delete all of my users' cookies for my website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

Basically, after making some changes to my website, the cookies my users have stored break it. Obviously, I can't go one by one and have the users delete them, so how can I force it from the website? The difference for my issue, is that I want to delete all of the cookies.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this cases that we set cookie in the client side, we can set a code in the first lines of our application and remove that coockie like this:

In JavaScript:

```
document.cookie = NAME + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Or in PHP:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['NAME'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['NAME']);
    setcookie('NAME', null, -1, '/');
}
```

With this approach all users that visit your website again its cookie expires.

You can delete all cookies in PHP. please follow [how to delete all cookies of my website in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php) also for JavaScript [How can I delete all cookies with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript)

Comment: OK, but for this I need to know the cookie name, correct?

Comment: You can delete all cookies i edited my answer, and also one if you know its name