# how to remove cookies in react

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-oauth, passport.js

Im trying to add a logout functionality to my mern app where I only have google authentication using passportJS. I want to clear the cache and cookies on logout because if I don't it automatically logs me back in without asking for what account to choose.

The cookie im trying to delete is a https only cookie

I have tried what seems like every solution on the internet but none of them work

`logout`

```js
    document.cookie = "connect.sid=; Max-Age=0;secure;path=/"; // This worked only for the first time
// clears cache which works fine
    caches.keys().then((names) => {
      names.forEach((name) => {
        caches.delete(name);
      });
    });
    window.open(`${apiURL}/auth/logout`, "_self");
```

I have tried other solutions like: react-cookie, universal-cookie, js-cookie etc... But none of them seem to work either.

Does anyone know how to do this I have been stuck on this for a long time?

Comment: Are you sure you're clearing cookies for the right domain/subdomain and path? Check the browser's inspector for the exact details of the cookies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript for more details/exploration.

Comment: Also the cookie im trying to delete is a https only cookie

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a while I figured out that I cannot delete http only cookies so what I did was I simply used the `req.logout()` function on the backend to delete it

when you log the user out you simply redirect the user to this route which then deletes the cookie and redirects back!

```js
router.get("/logout", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  req.logout({}, (err: any) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong." });
    res.redirect(clientURL);
  });
});
```